# Mysql join allowing ID to be used as a button link on inner join on null value of linked table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am not sure how to phrase my question without some background information.

I have 2 tables: accounts and rosters

accounts
id - PK
stafffname

rosters
rosterID - PK
id - FK link to accounts table
monday
tuesday
etc..

I am trying to create an edit table in php.

This is my current output

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts LEFT OUTER JOIN rosters ON accounts.id=rosters.id 
WHERE stafffname<>'admin' ORDER BY rosters.week_start ASC, accounts.stafffname ASC";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
      if($result->num_rows > 0) 
        {
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
            $comments = str_replace('+', '<br/>', $row['comments']);
            $comments = str_replace('{', '<strong/>', $comments);
            $comments = str_replace('}', '</strong/>', $comments);
                echo '
                    <tr class><!-- 2nd row STAFF MEMBER 5-->
                        <td><!--Date Range-->
                       '.$row["stafffname"].'
                       '.$row["id"].'
                        </td>
                    <td><!--Date Range-->
                       '.date("d M Y", strtotime($row["week_start"])).'
                    </td>
                    <td><!--Mon Time-->
                        '.substr($row["mon_start"],0,5).' - '.substr($row["mon_end"],0,5).'
                    </td>
                    <td><!--Tue Time-->
                        '.substr($row["tue_start"],0,5).' - '.substr($row["tue_end"],0,5).'
                    </td>
                    <td><!--Wed Time--> 
                        '.substr($row["wed_start"],0,5).' - '.substr($row["wed_end"],0,5).'
                    </td>
                    <td><!--Thu Time-->
                        '.substr($row["thu_start"],0,5).' - '.substr($row["thu_end"],0,5).'
                    </td>
                    <td><!--Fri Time-->
                        '.substr($row["fri_start"],0,5).' - '.substr($row["fri_end"],0,5).'
                    </td>
                    <td><!--Sat Time-->
                        '.substr($row["sat_start"],0,5).' - '.substr($row["sat_end"],0,5).'
                    </td>
                    <td><!--Comments-->
                        '.$comments.'
                    </td>
                    <td><!--Comments-->
                    <a href="rcreate.php?id='.$row["id"].'&tabid=3" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Add</a>
                    <a href="redit.php?id='.$row["id"].'&tabid=3&rosterID='.$row["rosterID"].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</a>
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
                ';
                }
```

The query works fine and it list the users with the Null values.

What I am trying to get working is: there is an add and edit button connected to the row but when there is a null value in the rosters table, the id from the accounts table is not passed to the add or edit button.

Is there a way for the id to be passed to the add and edit button?

Do I need a different type of query.

I have tried Cross Joins and other combinations, but it only lists the ID when there is data in both tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with your `accounts` table on the left and your `rosters` table on the right. This means that SQL will return all records from `accounts` along with any matching records from `rosters` if they are found.

It sounds like you want to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` which will return records from both tables, joining them when they match the condition in the where clause.

Comment: Thanks. When I use a a FULL OUTER JOIN it says there are no records

Comment: Oh wait...do you mean join them on the id